# How to write test cases for a REST service hosted somewhere

Tags: web-services, rest, testing, rest-assured

I have to write the test cases for a REST service that is hosted somewhere in the universe.I have the base url where it is hosted. How to setup the test cases to ping that service and test on the response json body?

Comment: There are many opensource & commercial tools/technologies available to automate testing of Rest APIs. List includes [SOATest](https://www.parasoft.com/product/soatest/), [SoapUI](https://www.soapui.org/), [ReadyAPI](http://readyapi.smartbear.com/), [RestAssured](http://rest-assured.io/), [FitNesse](http://fitnesse.org/), [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) and lot more. Initially choose the tool which suits your requirement and go ahead.

Comment: are you still interested in answers and examples or did you find a solution?